# Autocomplete Rails Responsive Layout

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, easyautocomplete

I'm trying to get my search form back to mobile responsive.
data: { behavior: "autocomplete" } in the form triggers easy-autocomplete functionality. But the search form/layout becomes mobile unresponsive when I add "data: { behavior: "autocomplete" } " Please do you know how I can fix this in the easy-autocomplete css file?

```
    <%= form_with url: search_path, local: true, method: :get, :class => "" do |form| %>
<div class="input-group m-b-20">
<%= form.text_field :q, placeholder: "Search and select or hit enter", data: { behavior: "autocomplete" }, class: "form-control input-lg" %>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg"></button> </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: You mean, your page not mobile responsive after autocomplete?

Comment: Yes artgb, after autocomplete

Comment: Could you update your question with the mobile picture and desktop picture to understand more about behavior?